# How to unit test callbacks logic in javascript?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am passing a callback function to another function and the callback itself has a logic inside it which I want to unit test.

```
callback = (data) ->
    if(data.isValuePresent == "true")
        alert("Valid data")
    else
        alert("Invalid Data")

 funcWithCallback(callback)
```

Now how do I test the logic inside callback, "funcWithCallBack" is in a separate class so I can spyon it, and callback is a private function so I cannot call it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't test the callback as part of the `funcWithCallback`. You test `funcWithCallback` by providing your own, test callback (something like this)

```
funcWithCallback(data => expect(data.isValuePresent).toEqual("true"))
```

The callback itself is tested just like any other function, by passing a value and expecting a result. You'll have to replace `alert()` with a spy, and ensure it was called with the proper parameters.

Comment: but the problem is callback is a  private function, so I cannot test it directly

Comment: You don't test private functions. You test external behavior of the entire unit.

Comment: The external behavior can only be tested through funcWithCallBack, because it it calling the callback, which is not possible

Comment: @infantDev: If that's the case then the callback being a private function is a mistake. Consider it a bug and make it not private. If the only reason it's public is testability that's OK - proving that your code works is more important than encapsulation.